# MYSQL MyIsaM How to Join 2 statement select + select count

Tags: mysql, join, myisam

table:
postid|userid|post|replyto

post sql

SELECT * FROM table WHERE postid=12

total replies sql

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM table WHERE replyto=12

the expected result is the "post table" + how many replies to the post. replyto field is the target postid. somehing like :

postid|userid|post|replyto|totalreplies

Is there a possibility to join this 2 queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it as a SubQuery (>5.x only):

```
SELECT
    postid,
    userid,
    post,
    replyto,
    (SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM table
    WHERE replyto=12) AS totalreplies
FROM table
WHERE postid=12
```

I think joining might also work, but right now I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  postid, userid, post, replyto, det.nb
FROM
  table,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb FROM table) det
```